# Struts2 does not find HTML files

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm using Struts2 with the convention plugin. I know how to get it to find actionless JSP files, but I can't seem to get it to display actionless HTML files. I have a whole set of HTML files generated by javadoc which I want to display in my WAR file (which is the documentation WAR for the actual application).

I put all of the HTML files under WEB-INF/content. When I remove the `.html` from the links, the file is found, but I'm not going to do that for the hundreds of javadoc files.

How do I get it to display index.html, overview-summary.html, etc?

Comment: Where are those files ? What do you get trying accessing them, 404 ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything: "The result type is based on the extension of the file. The supported extensions are: jsp,ftl,vm,html,html."(sic) https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html If it is public javadoc you could also move it into a publicly accessible location. Note: seems they wrote html twice when it should be htm and html of course.

Comment: But the two don't have the same conventions, javadoc uses CamelCase names and conventions likes "-". Someone else can experiment... what have you tried, and what are the results?

Comment: I've provided more information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to access these files through action then you need to set `html` to be an action extension. Use `struts.action.extension` constant to do that.

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,html,htm,,"/>
```

BUT if these files are static resources why do you want to access them through the actions in the first place? Take them out of `WEB-INF` and access them directly.

Comment: So a better practice would be to place those files at the top level and not under WEB-INF/content? The convention plugin does not manage any of the files that are not under WEB-INF/content?

Comment: Files under web-inf cannot be accessed directly, S2 convention plugin is irrelevant.